# WordPress Answers Top User Swag

Tags: discussion

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you have at least 890 reputation and are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- WordPress Answers t-shirt in your size
- WordPress Answers die-cut, vinyl stickers
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: wordpress.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: wordpress.stackexchange.com sticker]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store as soon as we're able)</sub>

Comment: This definitely motivates me to contribute more! Maybe next time I'll be on the lucky list.

Comment: Cool. This should solve our participation problems.^^

Comment: Is there any terms and conditions E.G. You must live in the USA to qualify?

Comment: @Brady we ship internationally.

Comment: *Big Smile* These goodies will add nicely to my Stack Overflow coding mug :D

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Brady I just ordered a mug yesterday. Does the code function properly on it?!

Comment: great. Thanks a lot.

Many shirts outside of america ;) great community

Comment: Wow, thanks peeps! This is pretty dope, for real!

Comment: Simply the best community I'm a part of. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome. You've just made my day! Thanks a lot .)

Comment: Awesome! (moves bookmark higher on the list *grin*)

Comment: This is very very cool and a nice surprise! Thanks so much WordPress Answers / Stack Exchange!

Comment: Thank you very very much!!!! really appreciated...

Comment: Thanks guys! I will look forward to it :)

Comment: update: we're shipping the packages this week.

Comment: Just got mine although there was no pen or sharpie included. Not to worry I'm very happy with t-shirt. I can now flaunt my dedication to WPSE that little bit more :) Might even wear the t-shirt to this years WPUK.

Comment: @Brady i got reports from other users(from other sites) that SE pen 'n sharpie weren't included. I'll check with our office manager.

Comment: hmmm I didn't get a pen/sharpie either, I also noticed the stackexchange sticker was bound with an elastic band, but there was only one sticker (free elastic band or is something missing?) My colleague got a goodie bag too with no sharpie and superfluous elastic band

Comment: Still waiting for mine.  I was bugging the mailman today.

Answer (score 3):

Got my package - no pen or sharpie! Thanks though.

Comment: My friend got his package all opened up, tee and a couple of more things missing! It happens only in India ;)

Answer (score 2):

I got it today. Now I <strike>am become Death, the shatterer of worlds</strike> feel better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Awesome! So excited to get mine.

Answer (score 1):

Awesome! Thanks. Hope to get to the first page next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Great news after a long week, love me some WordPress swag.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the token of appreciation, I can't wait to see it live!

Answer (score 0):

When will these limited edition items be in the shop (approximate date -- if you know?) Really looking forward to getting that shirt! :)

Comment: The swag will take about 3-4 weeks to be mailed to the top users. After that we plan to put all of our top user swag in our [online shop](http://shop.stackexchange.com/) for purchase.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I submitted the form in Feb and still haven't received my package! Have also mailed Rebecca, but no reply yet!
Any help?</strike>

Got it last week, thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Use the contact us link at the bottom of this page. I had the same problem and it was quickly resolved.

Comment: Thanks Chris, mailing 'em right away!

Answer (score 0):

By the way, the certificate doesn't have your name printed on it, correct? Atleast mine didn't have my name on it! I mean, it would be nice with our names printed. I literally had to save it from my fellow WP developers as it is very easy to steal the certificate and show it as yours!